# How to insert 1000 items at a time using cursor?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Right now my sql query inserting all the rows at one time at the end of the fetch, but i want to insert 1000 items at a time, so that table wont be locked for as long while insert is going on.

**Query**

```
    DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT Some variables  FROM @CardNumbers
        OPEN cur


begin tran
            FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO Some variables

                        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN
                            BEGIN TRY 
                                select @id = @@CURSOR_ROWS
                                //INSERT
                            END TRY
                            BEGIN CATCH
                                        if (ERROR_NUMBER() = 2601)
                                            begin 
                                                set @DuplicateCardNo = @DuplicateCardNo + 1
                                            end
                                        else
                                            throw
                            END CATCH

                            FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO  Some variables
                        END
            commit tran


        CLOSE cur    
        DEALLOCATE cur
```

How can i achieve that?

Comment: don't do it with a cursor then -> insert mytable (col1, col2, col3) select val1, val2, val3 from myOtherTableOrWhatever

Comment: i need to make a check before i can insert for every row in table1 before i can insert data into table2

Comment: you could insert from cursor to a #temp table first then fast insert with insert/select to final destination. however most of stuff can de done without cursors in my experience.

Comment: Why not use INSERT ... SELECT * FROM source .. WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM target WHERE target.id = source.id)

Answer (score 0):

If you MUST go row-by-row, you'd be declaring and using a cursor. It's usually not a good idea, and I'd be curious why you need to do so. The tags on your question (fetch, while) imply that you already have some clue about cursors. The general form looks something like:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @num INT; -- other columns
```

-- EDIT added LOCAL STATIC READ_ONLY FORWARD_ONLY per comment below

```
DECLARE excruciatingly_slow CURSOR LOCAL STATIC READ_ONLY FORWARD_ONLY FOR 
    SELECT 1  --this is just a sample, your query (which you might want to supply) will differ
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 2;

OPEN excruciatingly_slow;    
FETCH NEXT FROM excruciatingly_slow
    INTO @num -- other variables
    ;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS > -1
    BEGIN
        -- Do something here
        INSERT destination_table
            (    column_list -- other columns...
            )
        SELECT @num -- other columns
            ;

        FETCH NEXT FROM excruciatingly_slow
            INTO @num-- other variables
            ;
    END;
CLOSE excruciatingly_slow;
DEALLOCATE excruciatingly_slow;
```

In most cases this would be better done with the INSERT...SELECT... constructs suggested by the other replies. There is a homework tag if this is course-related. I'm having trouble thinking of a case where a single insert would be better served by a cursor.

Comment: i agree it is a very slow approach, but the problem is that i need to make a duplicate check for every row in table1 before i can insert same row into table2

Comment: Can you not use [GROUP BY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx) to remove the duplicates instead?  This would allow you to switch to a set based query, which is where SQLs real strength lies.

Answer (score 0):

Three other possible options:

1. Use a `MERGE` statement that can check for collisions first using
   the `MATCHING` clause, and only `INSERT` when not matched.
2. Add the `IGNORE_DUP_KEY` option to the index (not normally recommended,
   depends on your specific use case) so that colliding insert will be
   ignored.
3. Pre compute the IDs that are safe to be inserted, then use that in a `JOIN` to select them and have them actually inserted.

All of these will out perform the cursor options.

If you really want the '1,000 at a time', add a counter in the while loop, a `BEGIN TRANSACTION` before it, a `COMMIT TRANSACTION` after it, and, within it:

```
IF @counter % 1000 = 0 
BEGIN
    COMMIT TRANSACTION
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
END
SET @counter = @counter + 1
```